# Передать в конструктор класса список аргументов

Tags: python-3.x, классы, конструктор

Ребят, помогите разобраться, как передать в конструктор класса список аргументов и пройтись циклом по этому списку?

```
class A():
    def __init__(self,*name):
        self.name = name

    def func(self):
        if self.name == 'a':
            print ('aaa')
        elif self.name == 'b':
            print ('bbb')
        elif self.name == 'c':
            print ('ccc')
```

Методом тыка понял, что можно передать туда аргументы ,собственно, через цикл:

```
letters = ['a','b','c']
for i in letters:
    letters = A(i)
    letters.func()
```

Но как-то мне кажется это громоздко. Может есть более "правильный" способ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не очень понятно, чего Вы хотите. Может быть, этого:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, *names):
        self.names = names

    def func(self):
        for n in self.names:
            if n == 'a':
                print('aaa')
            elif n == 'b':
                print('bbb')
            elif n == 'c':
                print('ccc')

a = A('a', 'b', 'c')
a.func()
```

Comment: Оно и требовалось. Затупил))